# Collada model not showing with texture where other Collada models working good

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, collada

I can load different Collada models into my iOS application
But only one model which I exported as like others is not working.

Textures are mapped under the Diffuse property and preview ball in properties panel working.

But Quick Proview in the project, mac preview, ARKit preview, SCN Assets file nothing shows with texture.

I tried to replace that with new texture image but failed in that too.

I don't know what is the reason for this issue.

Folder:

[image]

Properties:

[image: Properties]

Preview:

[image: Preview]

Comment: I would imagine it has something to do with the naming of the files. You shouldn’t put . in a name... try for example pink_02.png not things like pink.png002.png

Comment: I renamed as u said.. Still it didnt work